# How to properly use SwiftUI's Photo Picker to upload image?

Tags: swift, swiftui, photo-picker

I am using SwiftUI's native image picker and selecting/loading images works great. What I can't figure out is how to call the selected image when uploading the image to firebase. In my UploadPostView, I can't figure out what to call for the image in `viewModel.uploadPost(caption: caption, image: <??>))` I've tried calling the selectedImage but I get the error that it is not a UIImage.. I thought I had done the work to convert the data in to a UIImage in my imagepicker. Anyways, I am new to Swift and I feel like I'm missing something obvious so any help is appreciated!

**UploadPostView**

```
struct UploadPostView: View {
@StateObject var imagePicker = ImagePicker()
@State private var caption = ""
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode
@ObservedObject var viewModel = UploadPostViewModel()
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 16) {
                    if let user = AuthViewModel.shared.currentUser {
                        KFImage(URL(string: user.profileImageUrl ?? ""))
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                    }
                    TextField("Enter your post here", text: $caption,  axis: .vertical)
                        .lineLimit(5...10)
                }.padding()
                
                Spacer()
                
                if let image = imagePicker.image {
                    HStack {
                        ZStack (alignment: .top) {
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                .cornerRadius(4)
                            Button {
                                self.imagePicker.image = nil
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: "xmark")
                                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .padding(4)
                                    .background(.black)
                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                            }
                            .offset(x: 45, y: -15)
                        }

                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                
                HStack (spacing: 24) {
                    Text("Add to your post")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.darkGray))
                    
                    Spacer()

                    PhotosPicker(selection: $imagePicker.imageSelection) {
                        Image(systemName: "photo")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                    }.foregroundColor(Color(.darkGray))
                    
                    Button {
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "at")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                    }.foregroundColor(Color(.darkGray))
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .onReceive(viewModel.$didUploadPost) { success in
                if success {
                    mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Create Post")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button {
                    mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.darkGray))
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                       viewModel.uploadPost(caption: caption, image: image))
                    } label: {
                        Text("Post")
                            .font(.system(size: 18))
                            .bold()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UploadPostViewModel**

```
class UploadPostViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var didUploadPost = false
@Published var didDeletePost = false
let service = PostService()

func uploadPost(caption :String, image: UIImage?) {
    service.uploadPost(caption: caption, image: image) { success in
        if success {
            //dismiss screen
            self.didUploadPost = true
        } else {
            // show error message to user..
            
        }
    }
}
```

}

**ImagePicker**

```
@MainActor class ImagePicker: ObservableObject {

@Published var image: UIImage?
@Published var imageSelection: PhotosPickerItem? {
    didSet {
        if let imageSelection {
            Task {
                try await loadTransferable(from: imageSelection)
            }
        }
    }
}

func loadTransferable(from imageSelection: PhotosPickerItem?) async throws {
    do {
        if let data = try await imageSelection?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
            if let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                self.image = uiImage
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        image = nil
    }
}
```

}